# C# Identify responding zombie process

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

**The Environment:**

User is starting an application at his Client-PC

Application is connecting to an application server and starting a process at the server

User is doing some things an the application is crashing at the Client PC

The process at the application server is still running with 100% cpu usage

**Question:**

Is it possible to detect the running process at the application server as a zombie process? The "zombie" process is still responding. 
Is there a way to get the Port and IP address from the "zombie"? So I may can ping the client at the specific port.

I just don't know where I need to search to identify it, because the process can take 100% doesn't mean that its a zombie process. Maybe the user is doing some real things. I just need a 100% safe way, I just can't kill them and hope it was a zombie. This can cause huge damage to the company.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: Why is a zombie if the client didn't started it, it was another process in the server who created it, isn't it?

Comment: Any sufficiently advanced busy loop is indistinguishable from useful work. In other words, *define* "zombie" if it's not "a process that's not responding".

Comment: I did my best to describe it.... The Client is connecting the the application server and creates a process at the server to handle to communication between the database and the application. I just think that the "zombie" is still responding because I still get some informations about it like the cpu usage, creation date, ..., ... it takes much longer but I get the informations. So I just think its responding

Comment: You can't, just by peeking from the outside, tell if a process is being useful or not if you have no good definition of "work". Tell the application programmer to improve it so a broken client connection leads to the natural death of the server process. In general, it's safe to say that no application that isn't *designed* to occupy the machine completely (like a heavy number cruncher) is supposed to take 100% CPU for extended periods of time. "I killed it because it was hogging the machine for 5 minutes" is usually accepted as a valid line of reasoning.

Comment: Think of it this way: if you would *never* kill the server process if the client process *hadn't* crashed even if it was taking 100% CPU for long periods (because it might be doing good work), then you should never kill the server process period, since you can't tell from the server alone. Whether or not the client is still running shouldn't really matter for your trigger criteria. The only alternative is to detect it on the *client* side and implement some sort of cancellation.

Comment: Make the client and the server exchange ping messages every n seconds. If the server receives no ping from the client for n * x seconds assume the client is gone and proceed to shutdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and I think it's the best way to do this.

I analyzed a "dead" process and a regular process, the difference is that the alive process has at least 4 TCP connections and the dead process only 2. 
Alive Process = Client -> Applicationserver -> Database Server
Dead Process = Applicationserver -> Databaseserver

So actually I'm retrieving all tcp connections, filtering them by Linq and group by so get the dead processes.

Code:

```
List<TcpProcessRecord> processes = Tcp.GetAllTcpConnections();

            var filteredAnonType = processes.Where(n => n.ProcessName.ToLower().StartsWith(Properties.Settings.Default.ProcessToMonitor.ToLower()))
                                    .GroupBy(x => x.ProcessId).Select(group => new
                                    {
                                        NumberConnections = group.Select(t => t.RemoteAddress).Distinct().Count(),
                                        ProcessID = group.Key,
                                    }).Where(v => v.NumberConnections < Properties.Settings.Default.MinimumConnections);


            List<ProcessZombie> filteredProcesses = (from zombie in filteredAnonType
                                                     select new ProcessZombie(zombie.NumberConnections, zombie.ProcessID)).ToList();
```